# Push notifications don't vibrate and are silent

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have created push notifications using Parse which are successfully sent to my device (real-world, not a simulator). However, these push notifications appear silently, not vibrating my phone, nor making any sound to notify the user. This is the case if the phone is locked, and when the phone is on, but not running the app.

I have code in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method to play a sound, which is played when the app is running. However, how can I play a sound, and get my phone to vibrate, when the device receives a push notification whilst the app is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by sending the sounds file through an `NSDictionary`, as shown in the [parse documention](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-customizing-your-notifications).

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
  @"alert" : @"Jet fuel proven to melt steal beams!",
  @"badge" : @"Increment",
  @"sounds" : @"cheering.caf"
};
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannels:@[ @"Dank_Memes" ]];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data of your notification you need to add the `sound` key.  Here would be an example of a payload that would play a sound:

```
"data": {
     "alert": "Good Morning please open our app",
     "sound": ""
}
```

[Here](https://parse.com/questions/push-notification-default-sound) is more info on it.

[Here](https://www.parse.com/questions/custom-sound-in-push-notifications) is info on how to customize the sound.