# Push notifications with sound and vibration

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, notifications, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send push notifications to users when they receive a message, The notification is successful with showing a banner however it is silent and does not vibrate.

I am using Atom as the server to send the notification and the code looks like,

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  const fromId = snapshot.val().fromId;
  const toId = snapshot.val().toId;

  console.log('LOGGER --- fromId is ' + fromId);
  console.log('LOGGER --- toId is ' + toId)

  var message = snapshot.val();

  return admin.database().ref('/users/' + toId).once('value', snapshot => {

  var userWhoRecieved = snapshot.val();

return admin.database().ref('/users/' + fromId).once('value', snapshot => {
var userThatSent = snapshot.val();

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text
    
  },
  sound: 'default'
};

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWhoRecieved.fcmToken, payload)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.results[0].error);
  console.log('Succesfully sent message:', response);

})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(response.results[0].error);
  console.log('Error sending message', error);
   });
   })
   })
  })
```

below is how I am trying to get the notification to send the default sound and vibrate.

```
  var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text
    
  },
  sound: 'default'
};
```

When I send a message using the code above, I see the following error in my firebase functions log

[image]

I have tried a few other methods but those methods won't even get pushed through the terminal. What is the correct way to get this method implemented?

```
the issue with sound inside notification object 

    var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text
    sound: 'default'
  },
};
```

The lines of code above are how I am getting the error below.

```
/Users/wilcox.323/Downloads/OddJobs-master/functions/index.js:219
    sound: 'default'
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
ODEE236182:OddJobs-master wilcox.323$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to vibrate or not depends on user settings. Your application cannot supersede the values that a user sets in his device settings.

Have you checked your device settings ?

Also, please look at this question:

[Push notifications don't vibrate and are silent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786054/push-notifications-dont-vibrate-and-are-silent)

As you can see that user got things working by sending the file name in the correct format. Is it possible that you are specifying the sound incorrectly in the payload ?

**Here is the error:**

```
var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text
    
  },
  sound: 'default'
};
```

**Sound should be within the notification object.**

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload

You are probably receiving the error, because you put the sound key outside the notification object. If you want it to work, your payload should be in the format described in the documentation.

EDIT:

In your updated code, you have neglected to separate the sound key value pair with a comma. Update your code to this:

```
var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text,
    sound: 'default'
  },
};
```

Comment: Yes! My phone does not have do not disturb turned on and the orange switch isnt enabled either.

Comment: @zachwilcox If you go to Settings->Notifications -> Your App. Is sounds enabled ?

Comment: Yes it is enabled! sounds and banners are on

Comment: I just want to get the default sound

Comment: @zachwilcox Found the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried that previously but I receive the error in my updated question on the bottom.

Comment: @zachwilcox The code in your question is incorrect. If you would like some help, you should ensure that you're posting exactly what is running on your computer right now. Also, since you know that there is an error in how you've specified sound, you should correct the code you've described in the question.

Comment: i understand the code is incorrect, i tried your method and got the error in my update code on the bottom

Comment: @zachwilcox You still haven't updated your code in the question. Without being able to see exactly what you've typed, I cannot help you further as I need to go. I suggest you read the documentation as that will probably help you identify further issues.

Comment: @zachwilcox The error is clearly pointing out where the problem is. As you have not posted your updated code, I cannot debug the issue. But you know where to look now.

Comment: my code is exactly what i have i will try to dissect further. when i put sound inside of notification i am receiving the error message i posted

Comment: @zachwilcox That's incorrect. If you're putting sound inside of notification, show us how you're doing it. You still haven't updated your code to show what it looks like when you put sound inside notification.

Comment: I see, I have posted that code above the error message now.

Comment: @zachwilcox you forgot a comma. obviously you will have an error.

Comment: You were correct hope others learn from this simple mistake

Comment: @zachwilcox Thats ok. Everyone starts as a beginner. But if you want better results, I suggest paying more attention to detail both in documentation, as well as in writing your question. That way you can solve your own issues faster!! :)